# Как реализовать ограничение на отправку?

Tags: post, php

Вообщем у меня есть форма

```
<?
echo "<form method='post'>";
echo "<input type='text' name='komy' value = '@'/><br>От кого:<br>";
echo "<input type='text' name='otkogo'><br>Сообщение:<br>";
echo "<input type='text' name='msg'><br><p><input type='submit' value='Отправить'></p>
</form>";
?>
```

Она обращается к скрипту, который тоже находится в этом файле. Собственно вопрос, как реализовать ограничение на отправку? Т.е. чтобы отправка была один раз в 5 минут, к примеру. Заранее спасибо :)

Comment: @JavaBitz Уважаемый участник, у Вас 5% принятых. Наверное, Вам стоит просмотреть список Ваших тем и принять (знак галочка слева от ответа) те ответы, которые ответили на Ваши вопросы.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(isset($_POST['komy'])){
    if(!isset($_SESSION['last_post']) || time() - $_SESSION['last_post'] >= 5*60){
        //действия
    }

    if(!isset($_SESSION['last_post']))
        $_SESSION['last_post'] = time();
}
```

Минус: мы все равно привязаны к кукам.

Answer (score 0):

Записывайте в куки/сессию время последней отправки и сверяйте: если оно на 5 минут меньше настоящего времени, то добро, иначе посылайте к ...

Comment: Есть ссылки на пример этого? И хотелось бы не по кукам, а по IP реализовать...

Comment: Если по IP, то геморнее. Записывайте в бд IP+время, затем сверяйте каждый раз перед отправкой и обновляйте время в бд. И не забывайте про дин IP.

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно по IP, то придется сохранять запись в базе в таблице с полями "IP" и "дата отправки формы" с этого IP. Ну и соотв-но каждый раз смотреть эту таблицу, проверять.

Comment: можно посмотреть мануалы/примеры где-нибудь?